# Securely storing variables without session in zope

Tags: zope, storing-information

I want to store values in variables to access form another page (a.k.a State management).

Now I cannot use sessions since I have multiple Zope instances & if one fails the user need to be redirected to another Zope instance and one session is valid only for one Zope instance.

Now my remaining options are

1. submit a Hidden input tag using POST method
2. Passing through URL with GET method
3. Using cookies
4. Using Database (which I think is 'making simple things complex'.)

I am not even considering the first 2 methods and I think using cookies is not secure.

So is there a commercial or open source module that can securely (encryption etc.) do cookie management.

If not I will have to use a database.

Please inform me, if I am missing something.

Version - Zope 2.11.1

Comment: Aren't you making simple things hard by not using a cookie? *Any* state information with a browser requires either a cookie or a hidden form or URL variable. To make that properly secure, you need session management (e.g. Zope sessions or a backend database) to prevent the end-user from altering those values.

Comment: Is 'Session cookies' called session & 'persistent cookie' called cookie ?[Check this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260971)

Comment: Cookies are cookies, which can either be persistent or not (in-memory). In this context (of this question) a session cookie is a unique value stored in a cookie to represent a browsing session for the server to track. You can use a persistent or in-memory cookie for that. See [session management](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_management).

Answer (score 0):

The SESSION support built-in to Zope 2 actually keeps the session in a temporary partition of the ZODB so I think it actually *is* valid for multiple Zope clients connecting to the same ZEO server.  The cost of this is that all session changes invoke the transaction machinery and result in a commit, so just make sure you're not using the SESSION in something very low-level like PAS auth or you'll have commits hitting your ZODB for every image, CSS file, and JS file.